# Error in running two loop functions concurrently in loop

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have defined these functions below:

```
def run1():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
      max_profit(),
   ))
def run2():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
      check_sell()
   ))
def run3():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(check_buy())
def run4():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(usdt_dispatcher())
def run5():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(binance_socket())
if __name__ == "__main__":
   bot = Application.builder().token(token).build()
   bot.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start))
   bot.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handler))
   bot.add_handler(conv_make_button)
   bot.add_handler(conv_change_networks_diff)
   bot.add_handler(conv_change_erc20_diff)
   bot.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Regex("Users"),user_list))
   bot.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Regex("Buy/Sell"),turnoff))
   bot.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Regex("Black List"),inlines))

   threading.Thread(target=run2).start()
   threading.Thread(target=run1).start()
   threading.Thread(target=run3).start()
   threading.Thread(target=run4).start()
   threading.Thread(target=run5).start()
   bot.run_polling(1.1)
```

and when I run this code I faced this error:
'''
Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError("Task <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<check_buy() running at Edited_Version.py:373> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:180]> got Future  attached to a different loop")
'''
how can I solve it?

note: check_sell and check_buy have an infinite loop inside.

Comment: I think there should only be one event loop per Python process. Maybe use `get_running_loop` or `get_event_loop` instead of `new_event_loop`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop